# How to chain joins in gorm?

Tags: mysql, sql, go, orm, go-gorm

I want to write a query like

```sql
SELECT table_a.*, table_c.* 
FROM table_a 
  LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id
  LEFT JOIN table_c ON table_b.id = table_c.table_b_id
WHERE table_a.column_a = 'a_value',
  AND table_c.column_b = 'some_value'
  AND table_c.column_c = 'another_value';
```

EDIT: I missed out quite an important point in that **the where clause variables are not fixed**. Depending on input, there may be more or fewer columns used for each table.

Currently, my query looks like

```golang
db.Table("table_a").
    Joins("left join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id").
    Joins("left join table_c on table_b.id = table_c.table_b_id").
    Select("table_a.*, table_c.*").
    Table("table_a").Where(map[string]interface{}{"column_a": "value"}).
    Table("table_c").Where(map[string]interface{}{
        "column_b": "some_value", 
        "column_c": "another_value",
    }).
    Find(&elem)
```

However, the logged SQL statement is

```sql
SELECT table_a.*, table_c.* 
FROM `table_c` # gorm gives the wrong starting table, should be table_a
  LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id 
  LEFT JOIN table_c ON table_b.id = table_c.table_b_id 
WHERE (`table_c`.`column_a` = 'value') # wrong table again
  AND (`table_c`.`column_b` = 'some_value') 
  AND (`table_c`.`column_c` = 'another_value')
```

I'm not sure what's the issue here. Is it that simultaneous queries for different tables isn't possible with this syntax? I would prefer to avoid using the raw queries as much as possible.

UPDATE: I've tried dynamically generating the SQL where clause, but would prefer if there is a more straightforward way offered by gorm.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call this many `Table` methods. It uses the last one that you've called to construct your SQL query.

Instead, once you have joined the tables, you can use them in the `Where` statements that come after the joins.

Try this:

```
db.Table("table_a").
    Joins("left join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id").
    Joins("left join table_c on table_b.id = table_c.table_b_id").
    Select("table_a.*, table_c.*").
    Where("table_a.column_a = ?", "value").
    Where("table_c.column_b = ? AND table_c.column_c = ?", "some_value",  "another_value").
    Find(&elem)
```

Comment: Sorry, missed out the fact that the where clause is not fixed, which is why I use a map for that. Is there any way to force a where with an interface argument to use a specific table?

Comment: If `TableA` model corresponds to your `table_a` DB table, you can try changing the `Where` methods to `.Where(&TableA{ColumnA: "value"}).Where(&TableB{ColumnB: "some_value"}).Where(&TableC{ColumnC: "another_value"})`. I believe that the `Joins` methods are still needed though.